# Cannot access portion of control that extends beyond bottom boundary of a tall Form

Tags: c#, winforms

The height of my Form is set to 780 which is the maximum allowed limit.
I have added a Panel in my Form which extends beyond the bounds of the Form. The designer mode allows me to scroll only to the bottom of the Form, but not to the bottom of the Panel.

Due to this, I am unable to drag and drop controls to the bottom of the Panel.

See portion of image highlighted in yellow:

[image]

Comment: The length of my winform is set to 780 which is the maximum allowed limit. I have added a panel which extends beyond the length of the winform. In the designer mode i can view the form only till the end of the form. It wont allow me to scroll till the end of the panel

Comment: I want to go to the bottom of the panel, but the designer view allows me to scroll only till the end of the form. (highlighted in yellow in the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add controls to forms and need space more than maximum allowed, you can not do this with `Form Designer`. You should add `controls` to form programmatically like this:

```
public Form3()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Panel panel1 = new Panel();
     Label[] lblArr = new Label[100];//Use any control you want

     int y = 10;
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     {
         lblArr[i] = new Label();
         lblArr[i].Text = "lbl" + i;
         lblArr[i].Location = new Point(30, y);
         panel1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
         panel1.Size = new Size(600, 2500);
         panel1.Controls.Add(lblArr[i]);
         y += 25;
     }

     this.Controls.Add(panel1); 
}
```

**Also** set the `AutoScroll` property on the `Form` to `True` in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum height of the `Form` is generally tied to the current resolution of your screen, so it's expected behavior to not be able to access the control that's partially off the bottom of the `Form`.

One way to get around it would be to set the `AutoScroll` property on the `Form` to `True` in the designer, so you could scroll down and access the entire `Panel`, the set it back to `False` in the designer or at runtime.

In the screenclip below, you can see two vertical scrollbars. The one on the far right allows you to scroll the entire Form up and down, but won't give you access to the rest of your Panel. The one to the left of it will scroll the *contents* of the Form up and down, and will allow you to access the Panel.

[image]

Or move the `Panel` up, do the work you need to do in it, and then move it back in place, again either at design time or at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Grant, I have set the auto-size property of the form to true, still cant reach the bottom of the panel in designer view.

Comment: both auto size and auto scroll is set to true. Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

When the number or size of panels don't allow to see all panels simultaneously in the designer. You may operate as follow:

In design mode:

```
- Create a TabControl with 2 or more tabPages,
- In TabPage0, create a MainPanel (Dock=Fill) to put most of the form controls,
- In other TabPage(s), put your additional panels.
```

At form create:

```
- Set the Parent property of MainPanel, i.e. mainPanel.Parent=this,
- Same for the Panels in other TabPages and update their location,
- Set the Parent property of the TabControl to null
```